# How to execute some command when someone cd to a specific directory

Tags: linux, unix

Is there a way in unix/linux to execute a command when you cd to it?

I am thinking of something like

- create a file 'autcd.cmd' inside /a/b/c with a set of commands
- the moment someone does 'cd /a/b/c' , autocd.cmd should be executed.

Is there a simple way to do this other than hacking the filesystem?

Comment: Why do you want this? It is probably a bad thing to do, and you don't define what you mean by "someone cd to a directory"  (are you thinking of the shell builtin -ignoring all other programs than shells- or are you thinking of the `chdir` system call [for which the answer is "No, thanks God!"])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could globally [alias](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) `cd`, and have that alias check the path being cd'd to. But otherwise, there's no standard method for triggering something when someone enters into a directory. There's never been a standard "autorun" type thing in Unix as there is on Windows (which is a good thing).